# Texture looks different in another scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I copied all the objects from the first scene

[image]

to the second scene

[image: second]

and all the settings for the objects are the same, but the color of the material (in the inspector too) looks different.

I tried to re-assign the texture to the cube in second scene, but nothing has changed.

When I copied the file scene1.unity to same folder like scene3.unity, all the colors in scene3 are correct, but what's wrong with scene2.unity?

Comment: try reassigning the materials .It shouldn't be a problem have you done anything else as well

Comment: @SouravSachdeva it does not work

Comment: Did you try restarting unity?

Comment: @Bizz Yes, but nothing changes

Comment: my second guess is that the properties of the material is being changed somewhere in code.

Comment: Did you check the Fog Settings? It might be the case that fog is being applied to a specific scene

Comment: If none of the previous comments helped you then check the light. it may be the direction of the light or something.

Comment: @Cabrra I copied ALL objects from scene1 with camera and lighting

Comment: I experienced this behavior. To be honest it never happens once I deploy a build. Try that and if it still happens then you should put a ticket on Unity support.

Comment: @JohnKramer I think , it's the problem with standard shader trying removing that component and assigning it again